# react-bootstrap loses focus after disable/enable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I cannot get an input to keep focus using a react-bootstrap [FormControl](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/forms/form-control/#form-control-props). It seems that disabling, then enabling the control removes focus. This is an uncontrolled input, but have the same issue with controlled. [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/kcgezr58/1/)

```
const SearchInput = ({onChange, ...props}) => {
  return (
    <Form
      onSubmit={evt => {
        evt.preventDefault();
        onChange();
      }}
    >
      <Form.Control {...props} />
    </Form>
  );
};

const App = (props) => {
  const [search,setSearch] = useState();
  const [searching, setSearching] = useState(false);
  const handleSearch = () => {
    setSearching(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setSearching(false)
    }, 2000);
  };
 return (
  <div>
    <SearchInput
      autoFocus
      disabled={searching} /* if this line is removed, focus remains */
      defaultValue={search}
      onChange={handleSearch}
    />
    <div>{search}</div>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Try using `setTimeout(() => ref.current?.focus())` in the `useEffect`.

Comment: @Unmitigated I did. And up to 500ms. And I tried useLayoutEffect

Comment: That's strange. I can't reproduce the issue. Could you provide a [mre]?

Comment: @Unmitigated - reproduced with a minimal example, but an entirely different question now